# What is the jQuery way to convert a Javascript object to JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/json2.js"></script>
</head>
    var EmployeeSerialized = JSON.stringify(GetInput()); //Convert object to JSON string

    **var myobj = jQuery.parseJSON(EmployeeSerialized);   //Use jQuery lib to translate JSON to Javascript object**
    var myobj2 = JSON.parse(EmployeeSerialized);        //alternative way: Use Json2.js lib to translate JSON to Javascript object

function GetInput()
{
    var emp = new Object();
    emp.Name = 'Brij';
    emp.Age = '27';
    return emp;
}
```

What is the jQuery way to convert a Javascript object to JSON without using the JSON2.js library?

Comment: I don't think jQuery provides this natively.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/912247/413670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply answer: sorry, jQuery does not support encoding into JSON, you have to use either native browser support or `json2.js`

Comment: I'm confused: I used jQuery to convert JSON to an object. var myobj = jQuery.parseJSON(EmployeeSerialized); if jQuery can convert one way, why not the other?

Comment: Because for JavaScript to parse JSON is extremely easy (since JSON is a subset of JavaScript). Generating JSON actually requires effort since the compiler can't be used to do that.

Comment: @Velika, there is usually very little reason to convert an object to string form in JS. It's often more important to get data from an AJAX call in string form.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Interesting. In my Hello World example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252274/having-trouble-with-a-simple-json-hello-world-app, I pass a JSOn representation of a JavaScript object to the server. Are you saying that I can pass the JavaScript object directly? I'm assuming not. i was looking at using an object as a way to pass multiple values to the server.

Comment: @Velika, if you're passing data to a server via JS, you ought to be using HTTP request variables of some sort, such as GET, POST, PUT. Forms are often used for this, but in jQuery it's as simple as `$.post(url, data, callback);`